# Is it possible to sync custom calendar using Google Calendar APi with native iOS and Android calendar

Tags: android, ios, calendar, google-calendar-api

After looking through all the documentation of the [Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/). I am still wondering if it's possible to export or sync this calendar with the Android calendar or iOS calendar(depends on user's device). I'm asking this because I want to make an application with a build-in calendar function which uses the Google Calendar API.

Comment: it should be possible.

Comment: No, I don't think this is supported by Calendar API yet as of now. File a request [here](https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Feature%20request). But if you're going to use external libraries, then they may have features for this.